# xargs pipes with multiple commands

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am trying to find all files older than 30 days with type .pkl in a directory, get the parent directory of found files and remove them.
My solution looks something like this:

```
find path_to_dir/.cache -type f -name "*.pkl" -mtime +30 |
  xargs dirname | xargs rm -r
```

Is there a way to avoid the double xargs?
Also, a further task of mine would be to delete all log files, but not parent directory. i.e.

```
find path_to_dir -type f -name "*.log" -mtime +30 -delete
```

Could I do above in one line without code replication?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using GNU find, you can use the `%h` token in the `-printf` command:

```
find path_to_dir/.cache -type f -name '*.pkl' -mtime +30 -printf '%h\0' |
  xargs -0 rm -r
```

For combining the two operations, something like this might work:

```
find path_to_dir/ -mtime +30 -type f \( -name '*.pkl' -printf '%h\0' -o -name '*.log' -print0 \) |
  xargs -0 rm -r
```

...but that assumes that you can use the same starting prefix for both operations (in your example, you're using `path_to_dir/.cache` in the first case and `path_to_dir` in the second case).

Comment: Thank you. What exactly does the %h token do? I tried to figure this out with man printf or googling, but couldn‘t really find an answer

Comment: You don't want `man printf`, you want `man find`, because this is the `find` command. You'll find the `%h` token and others documented with the `-printf` option (see https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html).